# TestUtils.renderIntoDocument return null, if it declared as anonymous function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I have 2 variants of code:

FIRST (declare as class):

```
export default class COMPONENT_NAME extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.props = props;
    }
    ....
    render = () => <div className="clName"></div>
}
```

SECOND (declare as anonymous function):

```
export default (props) => <div className="clName"></div>
```

JEST CODE:

```
jest.dontMock('../js/components/COMPONENT_NAME/index');
const COMPONENT_NAME = require('../js/components/COMPONENT_NAME/index.js').default;
var loaderComponent;
...
...
function renderComponent() {
    loaderComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <COMPONENT_NAME />
    );
}
```

Why test works only in the first case?

In the second case *renderIntoDocument* return null.
I can't find any information about it.

So the question is - does JEST support rendering anonymous functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing

```
jest.dontMock('../js/components/COMPONENT_NAME/index');
```

to

```
jest.unmock('../js/components/COMPONENT_NAME/index');
```

Comment: Faced exactly the same issue. tried unmock instead of dontMock but does not work.

Answer (score -1):

You should wrap your functional component into `div` when passing it to `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument` function:

```
function renderComponent() {
    loaderComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <div>
            <COMPONENT_NAME />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: already tried, don't help:
     Invariant Violation: findAllInRenderedTree(...): instance must be a composite component